# How To Fix create() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given In python django

Tags: python, html, django

I'm Creating Login & Register Form In Django. I got an error `create() takes 1 positional argument but 5 were given`.

code:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST['username']
        name=request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']
        user_create = User.objects.create(username,name,email,password)
        user_create.save()
        messages.success(request, " Your account has been successfully created")
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("404 - Not found")
```

html

https://paste.pythondiscord.com/amoturoqop.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should work with [**`.create_user(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.UserManager.create_user) and work with *named parameters*, not positional ones:

```
user_create = User.objects.create_user(
    username=username,
    first_name=name,
    email=email,
    password=password
)
```

The `.create_user(…)` function will hash the password such that the user can be authenticated properly.

While the first three parameters are `username`, `email` and `password` and you thus *can* pass these as positional parameter, I would advise against that since *explicit is better than implicit* (part of *The Zen of Python*).

Since `.create_user(…)` will save the object in the database, you do not have to `.save()` the `user_create`:

```
def register(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username=request.POST['username']
        name=request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']
        User.objects.create_user(
            username=username,
            first_name=name,
            email=email,
            password=password
        )
        messages.success(request, 'Your account has been successfully created')
        return redirect('/')
    else:
        return HttpResponse('404 - Not found', status=404)
```

Answer (score 2):

**Try this:**

```
def register(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        username=request.POST['username']
        name=request.POST['name']
        email=request.POST['email']
        password=request.POST['password']

        instance, created = User.objects.update_or_create(
            username=username,
            defaults={'username': username, 'name': name, 'email': email, 'password': password},
        )

        if created:
            messages.success(request, " Your account has been successfully created")
        else:
            messages.success(request, " Your account has been successfully updated")
        
        return redirect("/")
    else:
        return HttpResponse("404 - Not found")
```

**Explanation:**

As you face `UNIQUE constraint failed: auth_user.username` issue so `update_or_create` will resolve your that. It will update the data if any existing one found else it will create it.

> If User exists with `username=username` then update values with defaults, else create new User with defaults values

Comment: But won't that make the account sensitive to "hijacking". If person A has an account. The person B can use the username and thus pretend to create an account. As a result the credentials are now no longer those of person *A*, but of person *B*, and thus person *B* might have access to all the data of person *A*.

Comment: yes, your issue is valid. we can use django's default `create_user`